# Silverlight 4 SDK directory path and windbg?

Tags: silverlight, windbg

I want to use Windbg to debug a silverlight 4 application.

I can see that SilverLight SDK 4 and 5 are installed on my machine. When I check the directory folders I find : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.20913.0.

My question is should there be a 4.XXXX folder as well in order for my to use Windbg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking at the client install folder. I don't think Silverlight will allow both client versions to be installed at the same time.

Comment: Client install folder, is that not the SDK folder? Currently we are only doing silverLight 4 in development, should I uninstall both and re-install 4?

Comment: Keep in mind that even though your project may be compiled against Silverlight 4, most users are running the version 5 client as that gets pushed out with windows update. You can uninstall the client (not the SDK) in Add/Remove programs as described here: http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx I didn't have much luck finding the V4 client, but it may be part of the V4 SDK.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the information. Silverlight 5 it is...our app is leaking all over the place, so hopefully some of the leaks will have been resolved.